# In Amazing adapter crashing if list scrolled to bottom and new adapter set with less data

Tags: android

In my app I am using [amazing adapter](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/). The first time I display a list of elements, for example 20 elements. After scrolling down that ListView and changing the spinner the next time the list of elements is less than the first list and the app crashes.

How can I solve this problem?

My Adapter Class

```
public class SectionComposerAdapter extends AmazingAdapter {
    List<Pair<String, List<Color1>>> all;
    Context context;
    public SectionComposerAdapter(Context activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=activity;
    }
    public SectionComposerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity,
            ArrayList<Color1> planetlist1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    }
    public SectionComposerAdapter(
            Context activity,List<Pair<String, List<Color1>>> all) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=activity;
        this.all=all;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            res += all.get(i).second.size();
        }
        return res;
    }
    @Override
    public Color1 getItem(int position) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            if (position >= c && position < c + all.get(i).second.size()) {
                return all.get(i).second.get(position - c);
            }
            c += all.get(i).second.size();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNextPageRequested(int page) {
    }
    @Override
    protected void bindSectionHeader(View view, int position, boolean displaySectionHeader) {
        if (displaySectionHeader) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView lSectionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header);
            lSectionTitle.setText(getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
        } else {
            view.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getAmazingView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View res = convertView;
        if (res == null) res = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_composer, null);

        TextView lName = (TextView) res.findViewById(R.id.lName);
        TextView lYear = (TextView) res.findViewById(R.id.lYear);
        TextView lTopic = (TextView) res.findViewById(R.id.ltopic);

        Color1 Color1 = getItem(position);
        lName.setText(Color1.name);
        lYear.setText(Color1.time);
        lTopic.setText(Color1.code);
        return res;
    }
    @Override
    public void configurePinnedHeader(View header, int position, int alpha) {
        TextView lSectionHeader = (TextView)header;
        lSectionHeader.setText(getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
        lSectionHeader.setBackgroundColor(alpha << 24 | (0xeeeeee));
        lSectionHeader.setTextColor(alpha << 24 | (0x444444));
    }
    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        if (section < 0) section = 0;
        if (section >= all.size()) section = all.size() - 1;
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            if (section == i) { 
                return c;
            }
            c += all.get(i).second.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("Dude","all"+all.get(i).second.size());
            if (position >= c && position < c + all.get(i).second.size()) {
                return i;
            }
            c += all.get(i).second.size();
        }
        return -1;
    }
    @Override
    public String[] getSections() {
        String[] res = new String[all.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            res[i] = all.get(i).first;
        }
        return res;
```

}
    }

Comment: Share your adapter class code along with proper stack trace

Comment: By "amazing adapter" do you mean https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/?

Comment: yes that one only. in that issues issue number 7. i am not getting where i need to change

Comment: Show your adapter class code.

Comment: what i did mistake in adapter class